# How to retrieve unique data from SQL column without changing the actual order?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have  a column with guids and has duplicate entries.
e.g. GuidTable

```
guid
------------------------------------
7AAB93D4-3DAC-46F4-8E2A-2D43EF4033A0 

E753EBF7-3A13-4D25-B1BE-65BAD17F7097 

B9C61AAF-A625-4BF8-9BA8-8C4EFDA9E53B

B563F832-16A7-4F17-91C1-D9C5672DDB3E

**9FF90E75-16DD-4B01-9A1D-5BEB20564C63**

**9FF90E75-16DD-4B01-9A1D-5BEB20564C63**
```

If I perform 
Select distinct guid from GuidTable result is,

```
guid
-------------
7AAB93D4-3DAC-46F4-8E2A-2D43EF4033A0

9FF90E75-16DD-4B01-9A1D-5BEB20564C63

E753EBF7-3A13-4D25-B1BE-65BAD17F7097

B9C61AAF-A625-4BF8-9BA8-8C4EFDA9E53B

B563F832-16A7-4F17-91C1-D9C5672DDB3E
```

Here the order of the data retrieved is changed, i.e.not the actual order in table.

How to overcome this?
I need non-sorted data(should be same as of table order) with distinct guids.

Many thanks in advance.. :)enter code here

Comment: Use ORDER BY  to sort result

Comment: I do not  need the customized order.. I need the order exactly how it is in table with distinct result.

Comment: Do you know there is no such thing as ordered table? The only thing that sort result is `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: Thanks for reply..but i should get the data from table as it is with out duplicate rows...I observed distinct Key word changing the order of rows..Key is I do not need any Explicit sort..

Comment: Do you know that query optimizer can retrieve data in any order or use parallel processing? The order is not guaranteed. Do you have any ID IDENTITY/create date column in your table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is no such thing as ordered table. Query optimizer can retrieve data in any order especially when parallel execution is involved. The only way to guarantee the order is to use `ORDER BY` clause. If you have column in your table like: `ID IDENTITY` or creation date you can use it to order result set.

If not you can create "semi row number":

**[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/372523)**

```
CREATE TABLE #GuidTable(guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER);

INSERT INTO #GuidTable(guid)
VALUES
('7AAB93D4-3DAC-46F4-8E2A-2D43EF4033A0'),
('E753EBF7-3A13-4D25-B1BE-65BAD17F7097'),
('B9C61AAF-A625-4BF8-9BA8-8C4EFDA9E53B'),
('B563F832-16A7-4F17-91C1-D9C5672DDB3E'),
('9FF90E75-16DD-4B01-9A1D-5BEB20564C63'),
('9FF90E75-16DD-4B01-9A1D-5BEB20564C63');

SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
INTO #temp
FROM #GuidTable;

SELECT guid, MAX(rn) as rn
FROM #temp
GROUP BY guid
ORDER BY rn;
```

*Warning! This may not preserve the order if data is not pulled sequentially. As I've written earlier you need another column for ordering.*